# Using the trim function to narrow down results set

Tags: mysql, trim

I need to gather data from two columns, concat them so that it's only the first six of the first column and the last six of the second column, separated by ' + '. Some have been input with weird spaces in front or in back, so we must also use the trim feature and get rid of all NULL. I haven't had any issues with the first part, but am struggling to use the trim feature in a way that gives the desired output.
Output needs to look like this:

[image: neededoutput]

Input Data sample:

[image: sample]

The following code returns results, but the output doesn't match so I know the trim is wrong:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(baseball, 1, 6), ' + ',
SUBSTRING(football, -6)) AS MYSTRING 
FROM datenumtest2  
WHERE baseball IS NOT NULL AND football IS NOT NULL;
```

I also tried the following, but get an error message about the parameters being incorrect:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(baseball, 1, 6)), ' + ',
SUBSTRING(RTRIM(football, -6))) AS MYSTRING 
FROM datenumtest2
WHERE baseball IS NOT NULL AND
football IS NOT NULL;
```

I'm still new to this site and learning, but I have tried to include as much as I can! If there is other information that I can add to help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `Trim()` on the column(s), before using `Substring()` function on them:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(TRIM(baseball), 1, 6), ' + ',
              SUBSTRING(TRIM(football), -6)) AS MYSTRING 
FROM datenumtest2  
WHERE baseball IS NOT NULL AND 
      football IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much for your help! Seems like such a simple fix, I'm just still very new to it all! Appreciate your patience :)

Comment: @ColleenMorrison happy to help. :)

Comment: It's making me wait two minutes, but I will! Haha